# How to make a link to break in a paragraph

Tags: c#, asp.net

I ahve this code in asp that has a paragraph and a link in it. The issue is that the link that its getting is super long so it braks the design of the page, is there anyway to make it look like in a box (like if it had a line break). To be more specific I have a link that looks like this

```
http://www.google.com/cewcexxwrfrgregrfref/rferfrefrferfrefrf_jerfreferfrefrefrefrefrefer_freferfwrfwefewfewfwefewfwefefwefewfwefewf909ew0fwefwefwefwefwefwefwefwefewfwefewffwefwefwefwef99we0fwef__________________fwefwefewfewfw45453rwefwef
```

I want it to look something similar to this so that it doesnt break my page.

```
            http://www.google.com/cewcexxwrfrgregrfref/
            rferfrefrferfrefrf_jerfreferfrefrefrefrefrefer_
            freferfwrfwefewfewfwefewfwefefwefewfwefewf909e
            w0fwefwefwefwefwefwefwefwefewfwefewffwefwefwefwef99we0f
            wef__________________fwefwefewfewfw45453rwefwef
```

Here is the code

```
 <h4 class="SubTitle">
 Follow our Instructions</h4>
 <p>
   The instructions can be found in several places but we recommend:
     <br />
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUrl" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:LinkButton>
 </p>
```

Comment: Why are you showing a super-long URL to your user?

Comment: This is in an admin section of a website...to be used by only the admins.. PS: thats how the clients wants nothing we can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `word-wrap` attribute, this way:

```
a { display: block; word-wrap: break-word; }​
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86FEV/). So, in your code it could be:

```
<h4 class="SubTitle">Follow our Instructions</h4>
<p>
    The instructions can be found in several places but we recommend:
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUrl" runat="server" Style="display: block; word-wrap: break-word; width: 100px;"></asp:LinkButton>
 </p>
```

Comment: Its weird, when i add that css it says word-wrap is not a known CSS property.

Comment: Do you believe that Visual Studio tells the truth about CSS valid? Simply use it, the attribute is right and works correctly in all browsers.

Comment: I believe you, but since i dont see it working in this page its just driving me crazy... so much time spent on this .. which  looks like a simple fix

Comment: You don't see it working on what page? It's fine in the sample I posted, so it's the right attribute. Maybe you're using it in the wrong location, then I updated my answer to a more direct approach.

Comment: Yeah that was it, thank you very much for your patience and help

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in a div with width.  The browser will automatically wrap it for you.

```
<p>
   The instructions can be found in several places but we recommend:
</p>
<div style="width: 100px;">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUrl" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before, did not work, I tried it exactly with the code you pasted also .. still did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think this might work, apply this css class to your link
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 .nobreak{display:inline;}
 </style>
 </head>

 <h4 class="SubTitle">
  Follow our Instructions</h4>
  <p>
   The instructions can be found in several places but we recommend:
   <br />
  <asp:LinkButton cssClass="nobreak" ID="lnkUrl" runat="server" Width="100px">    </asp:LinkButton>
</p>
```